# Android App Restarted when "home" button is pressed

Tags: android, actionscript-3

I am new in Android app. I did one Android app using Flash Air for Android AS3. There are 5 Levels in that app. For Example, I am playing 3rd level, and I just come back by pressing home button. App running in the background. After some time(maybe 1 Hour) app gets reopened, it starts working from first screen.

I don't want to open the first screen. I need to play from where i left my app (i.e. 3 level).

Please reply.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Please replay me ASAP.` what is this? You asking help!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You must read first [Activity Life Cycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html) why it is starting from First screen. And for solution you have to save your data inside onPause() method (For smaller data and to save large data like  database you have to use onStop()) to save your data.

You can save data using [SharedPreference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)